# RegEx in Ng-Pattern Behaving Differently when in String, as Opposed to Var

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

When I use a RegEx as a string to only allow digits, it works fine, like so:

```
 <input ng-model="txtInputValueOne" 
        ng-pattern = "/^\d+$/">
```

When I use it with a variable, it does NOT work correctly ("working correctly" = allowing only digits into the input model result):

```
 <input ng-model="txtInputValueTwo" 
        ng-pattern = "intPattern">


$scope.regExString = "\d+"
$scope.intPattern =  new RegExp($scope.regExString);
```

What's the problem? [PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/0L8JqyqaGHd5xqY4TEG1?p=preview)

Comment: you are missing the "\\d+"

Comment: that doesn't do anything, it's an angular convention. Iirc ng-pattern forces it in there anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash

```
$scope.regExString = "^\\d+$"
```

Comment: Try "123abc" in both fields, the latter will accept it when it shouldn't.